# Using SVG in Titanium app

Tags: javascript, html, svg, titanium

I'm facing problem when I update my SVG file with `innerHtml` data everything shows well but only in the image tag "xlink:href" attribute. If I use the "href" attribute for this instead, my image does not show in the SVG browser. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Its hard to help you from what your giving us, can you show some code, tell us what platform your using, and give some context?